# If $g'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, how to prove $\frac{g(x)}{x} \to 0$ as well

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $g'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, how to prove rigorously that $\frac{g(x)}{x}  \to 0$ as well?

It's tempting to write $g'(x)$ is of order $0$ and $x'$ of order $1$; hence $\frac{g(x)}{x} \to 0$ for sure. Can anyone give a hint about how to write this rigorously please?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $|g'(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x>x_0$. Then by MVT for some $\xi\in(x_0,x)$
$$ \left|\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}\right |=|g'(\xi)|<\epsilon$$
But
$$ \frac{g(x)}{x}:\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\frac{1-\frac{x_0}x}{1-\frac{g(x_0)}{g(x)}}$$
tends to $1$ - unless possibly $g(x)$ becomes small anyway.

Comment: (That's L'Hôpital in disguise!)